# how can I use multi-threading in a c++ application on a mac?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need to add threading to my code below, whats a quick way to do so?

```
int main() {
    ObjectType obj1;
    ObjectType obj2;
    printMaze(obj1, obj2);
    getUserInput(obj1, obj2);
    return 0;
}

void printMaze(ObjectType&obj1, ObjectType&obj2){
    ///
    ///
    ///
}

void getUserInput(ObjectType&obj1, ObjectType&obj2){
    ///
    ///
    ///
}
```

I want to be able to call printMaze and getUserInput in separate threads and also have them use the same variables [in essence share a variable].

Comment: Your request doesn't really make sense. Getting user input and then processing that input is inherently serial. You can't process the input until you get it. So why use threads for that?

Comment: In C++, the method you use to printMaze(...) should be part of class ObjectType.  You have not provided sufficient info to understand your choices, but the encapsulation idea is to invoke as obj1.printMaze().   It is possible to invoke "obj1.printMaze(obj2);" if you really need it.  Your goals should include the encapsulation of the data with the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just off the top of my head, this is a very quick way to implement threads on a Mac

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//contains all the information needed
struct AllInfo{
    ObjectType obj1;
    ObjectType obj2;
};

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    pthread_t printingThread;
    pthread_t inputThread;
    AllInfo info;
    pthread_create(&printingThread, NULL, &printMaze, &info);
    pthread_create(&inputThread, NULL, &getUserInput, &info);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
void *printMaze(void * infoArg) {
    AllInfo *info;
    info= ( AllInfo *)infoArg;
    ///
    ///
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *getUserInput(void *infoArg) {
    AllInfo *info;
    info= (struct AllInfo *)infoArg;;
    ////
    ////
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

you'll notice a couple of things
    when passing arguments into a function that will be called in a thread,
        [1] you can only pass 1 argument into that function so if you need to do more than 1 argument in the function call, you will have to bundle up the separate arguments together using a struct. and
        [2]when passing arguments into a function that is being called in a thread, you will need to first accept it from the function as a object of type "void *" before typecasting it back into its original "AllInfo" objecttype.

Comment: Why would you use `pthreads` when there is [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).  Not only is it more user-friendly, it is also portable.